# when i input stick the second time it doesnt print score so far like the first time, not sure why it skips this

Tags: ruby, methods, blackjack

### Task

> Write a program that lets a user player a solo game of
>   Blackjack. The program should:
>
> - Ask the player if they want to "hit" or "stick".
>
>   - If the player hits, add a card to their hand.
>   - If the player sticks, end the game.
> - Keep asking the player if they want to "hit" or "stick" until they
>     say "stick".
> - Each time the player hits, calculate the score for the player's
>     hand and `puts` `Score so far:` and the score.
>
>   - e.g. `Score so far: 23`
>   - A score is calculated by adding up the values of each of the
>       cards in the player's hand.
>   - Value for each card:
>   - "two": 2
>   - "three": 3
>   - "four": 4
>   - "five": 5
>   - "six": 6
>   - "seven": 7
>   - "eight": 8
>   - "nine": 9
>   - "ten": 10
>   - "jack": 10
>   - "queen": 10
>   - "king": 10
>   - "ace": 11 (This is slightly different from real Blackjack.)
> - When the game is over, `puts` the outcome of the game.
>
>   - If the player's score is `<= 21`, `puts` `You scored:` and the
>       final score
>   - e.g. `You scored: 20`
>   - If the player's score is `> 21`, `puts` `You busted with:` and
>       the final score.
>   - e.g. `You busted with: 25`
> - As part of your solution, there should be four specific methods:
>
>   - `random_card`: This has already been written for you.  You don't
>       need to change it.
>   - `move`: Asks the player for a move.  If they enter `hit` or
>       `stick`, it returns the move.  If they enter something else, it
>       keeps asking them until they enter `hit` or `stick`.
>   - `score`: Takes an array of cards and returns the score for the
>       hand as an integer.
>   - `run_game`: uses the other methods to run a game of Blackjack.
> - Note: When you run the automated tests, make sure to remove from
>     the top level of the file any calls to `run_test` or other
>     methods.
> - Note: To stop the game when the user sticks, don't use `exit` to
>     quit the program because this will break the automated tests.  To
>     exit a while loop early, use the `break` keyword.
>
> You don't need to change this method!

### Code

```
def random_card
  cards = ["two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten",
           "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"]
  cards[rand(13)]
end
random_card

def move
  puts "hit or stick?"
  turn = gets.chomp
  if turn == "hit"
    "hit"
  elsif turn == "stick"
    "stick"
  else
    move
  end
end

def score(array)
  values = {
    "two" => 2,
     "three"=> 3,
      "four" => 4,
       "five"=> 5,
        "six"=> 6,
         "seven"=> 7,
           "eight" => 8,
            "nine" => 9,
             "ten" => 10,
           "jack" => 10,
            "queen" => 10,
             "king" => 10,
              "ace" => 11
            }
           total = 0
           array.each do |card|
             total += values[card]
  end
  total
end

def run_game
 hand = []
  while move == "hit"
   hand.push(random_card)
   if score(hand) <= 21
   puts "Score so far: #{score(hand)}"
 else
     puts "you busted with #{score(hand)}"
     break
   end
     if move == "stick"
       puts "You scored: #{score(hand)}"
       break
   end
 end
end
run_game
```

Comment: The titles of questions are intended to give readers an idea of what the question is about. Yours does not do that. Your title should be part of the statement of the question, but rewritten to correct two problems. One is to clarify the problem with your code and to state your question. The other is to use proper English. Sentences begin with capital letters, the first-person pronoun "I" is capitalized, "doesn't" contains an apostrophe. SO is not a chat room. Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if move == "stick"
   puts "You scored: #{score(hand)}"
   break
```

You are calling your move function again.

Try this run_game function, the difference is calling move only once per loop.

```
def run_game
 hand = []
 currMove = move
 while currMove == "hit"
  hand.push(random_card)
  if score(hand) <= 21
   puts "Score so far: #{score(hand)}"
  else
   puts "you busted with #{score(hand)}"
   break
  end
  if currMove == "stick"
   puts "You scored: #{score(hand)}"
   break
  end
  currMove = move
 end
end
```